# CSS to select the first 4 elements in table

Tags: css

I want to select only the first 4 columns in the table below (highlighted in red)
How do I do that?

I have tried the following so far but it's not what I wanted.

table.foobardate

table.foobardate>tr:not(:last-child)

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Selector `nth-child()`: `-n` to start from begin. `+4` the next 4.

```
td:nth-child(-n+4)
```

Comment: I have tried using table.foobardate>tr>th:nth-child(-n+5) and table.foobardate>tr>td:nth-child(-n+5) and that seems to get all the data I wanted. However I'm losing the table formatting. Is there any trick to maintain the table formatting or put the data I'm getting back into a table?

Comment: @TuonCan You have now an array of elements (preferable 2 dimensional) and you can loop through them to put them back into a table. To do that check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Traversing_an_HTML_table_with_JavaScript_and_DOM_Interfaces

Answer (score 1):

## :nth-child

The `:nth-child` selector allows you to select one or more elements based on their source order, according to a formula. It is defined in the CSS Selectors Level 3 spec as a `“structural pseudo-class”`, meaning it is used to style content based on its relationship with parent and sibling elements.

Suppose we are building a `CSS` grid, and want to remove the margin on every fourth grid module:

```
<section class="grid">
  <article class="module">One</article>
  <article class="module">Two</article>
  <article class="module">Three</article>
  <article class="module">Four</article>
  <article class="module">Five</article>
</section>
```

Rather than adding a class to every fourth item (e.g. .last), we can use `:nth-child`:

```
.module:nth-child(4n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

As you can see, :nth-child takes an argument: this can be a single integer, the keywords `“even”` or `“odd”`, or a formula. If an integer is specified only one element is selected—but the keywords or a formula will iterate through all the children of the parent element and select matching elements — similar to navigating items in a `JavaScript` array. Keywords `“even”` and `“odd”` are straightforward (2, 4, 6 etc or 1, 3, 5 respectively). The formula is constructed using the syntax an+b, where:

> “a” is an integer value 
> “n” is the literal letter “n” 
> “+” is an
>   operator and may be either “+” or “-” 
> “b” is an integer and is
>   required if an operator is included in the formula

Ref: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/